# Django Rest Framework - how to use different query params format?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap4-table#8-filtering][1] with `django-rest-framework`.

The problem is that this component uses totally different query params for sorting, filtering, etc.

**vue-bootstrap4-table**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?queryParams=%7B%22sort%22:[],%22filters%22:[%7B%22type%22:%22simple%22,%22name%22:%22code%22,%22text%22:%22xxx%22%7D],%22global_search%22:%22%22,%22per_page%22:10,%22page%22:1%7D&page=1

"filters":[{"type":"simple","name":"code","text":"xxx"}],
```

whereas **Django-rest-framework** needs this format:

```
../?code__icontains=...
```

I want to figure out how to make `DRF` accept this format instead of the built-in?

I use just `ViewSet`.

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_class = ProductFilter
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It translates to:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/?queryParams={"sort":[],"filters":[{"type":"simple","name":"code","text":"xxx"}],"global_search":"","per_page":10,"page":1}&page=1

It almost looks as though you're still supposed to serialize these arguments into the correct format manually, or send them in the body of the request instead of as a query param.

I don't know of a painless way to get DRF to deal with this by automatically. However, since the value of 'queryParams' is valid JSON, you can override the methods you want on the ModelViewSet. [This page](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) describes the methods you can override. To get the json into a dict you can do `json.loads(request.query_params['queryParams'])`. From then on you can filter and order manually with the ORM.

Or, of course, you could turn the query params into 'regular' query params client side. This is a great lib that can help you out with that: https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/.

Also, it's generally ill-advised to allow users to order against any field. With products this is probably relatively low risk, but [don't make it a common practice.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-which-fields-may-be-ordered-against)